# upload image on didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo in UIWebview url

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I load the url in UIWebView, there is an option choose file where i have to open image picker controller and pick image. picked image should upload to that url.

Example:- "if profile view loaded into UIWebview than user can change their profile picture from the UIWebview, there is an option like choose file where user can open picker controller to pick image and set selected that image."

```
//Load url
  [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]]];

//open ImagePickerController
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[request URL] scheme]);
   if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
        [self showCamera];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
//PickImage
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *flatImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1f);
    NSString *Str = [flatImage base64Encoding];
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"processImage('data:image/jpeg;base64,%@')", Str];
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

I tried above code, but selected image not upload to that url which is loaded in UIWebview.

How to do this, what is wrong in this? if there is any solution than please suggest me.

Comment: Hi @Nikunj, Did you get any solution to this?